# compare 2 methods data.get('key_name') vs. `data['key_name'] or None`

Tags: python

I got a python dictionary variable called `data`, I am trying to get value of 'key_name', if it doesn't exists, I want it to be None.

```
A = data.get('key_name')

B = data['key_name'] or None
```

I know if the 'key_name' is a empty string, A is '' and B is None, and maybe there are some other reasons I did not consider, what else? Like, maybe A is safer than B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will throw a KeyError so you can't use this:

```
B = data['key_name'] or None
```

As far as Python goes, the first option is the most standard way to do that:

```
A = data.get('key_name')
```

If you are open to other data types, you can always use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects).

You can do this and it would work as well:

```
data = defaultdict(lambda: None)
C = data['key_name']
# C is now None
```

Often `defaultdicts` are used when you want a list to be created by default or something like that. The docs cover those cases.